# Biography of L. Euler

Tags: reference-request

Could you recommend a historically rigorous biography of L. Euler (if possible with discussions and examples of the mathematics he was doing)?

---

**Edit**: I'd rather prefer a book (not necessarily about Euler alone) or a thorough article.

Comment: Have you tried MacTutor?

Comment: @AsafKaragila yes, I'm looking for something more thorough (like a book or long article).

Comment: A good source (with not a complete set of info) may be 'A history of mathematics' by C.Boyer

Comment: I once took a course from this mathematician whose personal hero was Euler. Here is a presentation he gave on Euler. math.univ-lyon1.fr/~clarke/Clarke_Euler_Talk.pdf

Comment: Try 1. "Euler: The Master of Us All" By William Dunham, Published By Mathematical Association of America. 2. http://gbenthien.net/Euler/Euler.pdf

Comment: Look in the *Dictionary of Scientific Biography*, this is the only reliable source for mathematicians' biographies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard reference seems to be

> [Euler: The Master of Us All](http://www.maa.org/publications/books/euler-the-master-of-us-all) by William Dunham.

See also

> [Leonhard Euler](http://www.springer.com/br/book/9783764375386)
>   by Emil A. Fellmann.

There is a short article here:

> [Biography: Leonhard Euler](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2968971), 
>   by B. F. Finkel.
>   *The American Mathematical Monthly*,
>   Vol. 4, No. 12 (Dec., 1897), pp. 297-302

See also [The Euler Archive](http://eulerarchive.maa.org), in particular its [Historical and Biographical Resources](http://eulerarchive.maa.org/resources.html) page.